# How to create Company file in Quickbook Desktop and Quickbook Online?

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks

Is it possible to create new company file programmatically either using SDK or API? Or Is there any alternate solution to achieve this?

Comment: You should probably ask their Customer Support about that

Answer (score 1):

No, neither the SDK or API allows for creation of a company file. In theory, it is possible as Intuit's own ActiveX control creates a new file when converting from Online to Desktop, but Intuit has not made this process available outside of their company.